How to set different output qualities for MPEG-DASH?
I am trying to convert an MP4 to MPEG-DASH and the output is working fine. I can play the MPEG-DASH or manifest file through MPEG player.
However, is there a way to change the quality of the video without changing the size of original file?
Because when I try to put the sizing for different qualities like 1080p, 720p, etc. the output video is stretched.

You can't change the resolution on the fly.  To provide different choices for quality, there are source files encoded for each resolution.
To make DASH segments for 1080p, you would use:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f dash -window_size 1080 -profile:v main -level 4.0 -seg_duration 10 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" -segment_list_flags +live -reset_timestamps 1 -frag_duration 10 1080p.mpd

This provides the ability for quality selection, using dash.js. (I saved it to the directory and linked it locally.)
For example, if you're using HTML, you would need:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DASH Player</title>
    <script src="dash.all.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        :root {
            --bg-dark: #0f0f0f;
            --text-dark: #ffffff;
            --accent: #ced600;
            --neumorphic-dark: 3px 3px 5px #0d0d0d;
        }
        body {
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            min-height: 100vh;
            background-color: var(--bg-dark);
            color: var(--text-dark);
        }
        .container {
            max-width: 800px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #player {
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 15px;
            overflow: hidden;
            box-shadow: var(--neumorphic-dark);
        }
        .controls {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
            gap: 10px;
        }
        #qualitySelect {
            height: 42px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #222;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            border: 1px white gray;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all 0.2s;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            box-shadow: var(--neumorphic-dark);
            font-size: 1rem;
        }
        #qualitySelect:hover {
            background-color: #000;
        }
        .time-duration {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #currentTime, #duration {
            font-size: 1rem;
            margin: 0 10px;
        }
        #progressBar {
            flex-grow: 1;
            height: 10px;
            background-color: #111;
            border-radius: 5px;
            overflow: hidden;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 1px white solid;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            box-shadow: var(--neumorphic-dark);
        }
        #progressBar:hover {
            background-color: #000;
        }
        #progress {
            width: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: var(--accent);
            transition: width 0.1s linear;
        }
        button {
            background-color: #222;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            border: 1px white solid;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all 0.2s;
            box-shadow: var(--neumorphic-dark);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            width: 42px;
            height: 42px;
        }
        .red:hover {
            background-color: #000;
            border: 1px red solid;
        }
        .green:hover {
            background-color: #000;
            border: 1px green solid;
        }
        .sounds:hover {
            background-color: #000;
            border: 1px green solid;
        }
        .muted:hover {
            background-color: #000;
            border: 1px red solid;
        }
        .paused:hover {
            background-color: #000;
            border: 1px yellow solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <video id="player"></video>
        <div class="controls">
            <button id="play-pause" class="button green" aria-label="Play/Pause">
                <img src="svg/play.svg" alt="Play Icon">
            </button>
            <button id="stop" class="button red" aria-label="Stop">
                <img src="svg/stop.svg" alt="Stop Icon">
            </button>
            <div id="progressBar" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                <div id="progress"></div>
            </div>
            <select id="qualitySelect">
                <option value="480p">480p</option>
                <option value="360p">360p</option>
                <option value="240p">240p</option>
            </select>
            <button id="sound" class="button sounds" aria-label="Sound">
                <img src="svg/sound.svg" alt="Sound Icon">
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="time-duration">
            <span id="currentTime">00:00</span>
            <span id="duration">00:00</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const video = document.getElementById('player');
        const playPauseBtn = document.getElementById('play-pause');
        const stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop');
        const progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
        const progress = document.getElementById('progress');
        const currentTimeDisplay = document.getElementById('currentTime');
        const durationDisplay = document.getElementById('duration');
        const qualitySelect = document.getElementById('qualitySelect');
        const soundOnOff = document.getElementById('sound');

        let player;
        let isMuted = false;

        const qualities = {
            '480p': '/480p/480p.mpd',
            '360p': '/360p/360p.mpd',
            '240p': '/240p/240p.mpd'
        };

        function initializePlayer(quality) {
            if (player) {
                player.destroy();
            }

            player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
            player.initialize(video, qualities[quality], true);
            player.updateSettings({
                'debug': {
                    'logLevel': dashjs.Debug.LOG_LEVEL_NONE
                },
                'streaming': {
                    'abr': {
                        'useDefaultABRRules': true,
                        'ABRStrategy': 'abrDynamic'
                    }
                }
            });

            player.on('canPlay', updateDuration);
            player.on('playbackTimeUpdated', updateProgress);
        }

        playPauseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (video.paused) {
                video.play();
                playPauseBtn.innerHTML = `<img src="svg/pause.svg" alt="Pause Icon">`;
                playPauseBtn.classList.add('paused');
            } else {
                video.pause();
                playPauseBtn.innerHTML = `<img src="svg/play.svg" alt="Play Icon">`;
                playPauseBtn.classList.remove('paused');
            }
        });

        stopBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            video.pause();
            video.currentTime = 0;
            playPauseBtn.innerHTML = `<img src="svg/play.svg" alt="Play Icon">`;
            playPauseBtn.classList.remove('paused');
        });

        soundOnOff.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (video.muted) {
                video.muted = false;
                soundOnOff.innerHTML = `<img src="svg/sound.svg" alt="Sound Icon">`;
                soundOnOff.classList.remove('muted');
            } else {
                video.muted = true;
                soundOnOff.innerHTML = `<img src="svg/mute.svg" alt="Mute Icon">`;
                soundOnOff.classList.add('muted');
            }
        });

        function updateProgress() {
            const currentTime = player.time();
            const duration = player.duration();
            progress.style.width = `${(currentTime / duration) * 100}%`;
            currentTimeDisplay.textContent = formatTime(currentTime);
        }

        function updateDuration() {
            durationDisplay.textContent = formatTime(player.duration());
        }

        function formatTime(seconds) {
            const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
            return `${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
        }

        function seek(event) {
            const rect = progressBar.getBoundingClientRect();
            const pos = (event.clientX - rect.left) / rect.width;
            player.seek(pos * player.duration());
        }

        progressBar.addEventListener('click', seek);

        qualitySelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
            initializePlayer(e.target.value);
        });

        // Initialize with default quality (480p)
        initializePlayer('480p');
    </script>
</body>
</html>

python -m http.server
http://localhost:8000
live-server
http://127.0.0.1:8080
php -S localhost:5000
http://localhost:5000 (obviously.)
Run any of them from the same directory as index.html.
Here is an example directory.

Okay, thank you! I will try this

@FrancisEvangelista I noticed the unaccepted answer.  Did this not work?  I believe this is the only way.

is it possible to create a different qualities in one go of command in ffmpeg?

outputOptions([         '-preset', 'fast',         '-profile:v', 'main',         '-sc_threshold', '0',         '-g', '48',         '-keyint_min', '48',         '-use_timeline', '1',         '-use_template', '1',         '-init_seg_name', 'init-$RepresentationID$.m4s',         '-media_seg_name', 'chunk-$RepresentationID$-$Number$.m4s',         '-adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a"',         '-f', 'dash', 

// First quality         '-map', '0:v:0', '-b:v:0', '500k', '-filter:v:0', 'scale=-2:360',         // Second quality         '-map', '0:v:0', '-b:v:1', '1000k', '-filter:v:1', 'scale=-2:480',         // Third quality         '-map', '0:v:0', '-b:v:2', '1500k', '-filter:v:2', 'scale=-2:720',         // Fourth quality         '-map', '0:v:0', '-b:v:3', '2500k', '-filter:v:3', 'scale=-2:1080',         // Audio         '-map', '0:a?', '-c:a', 'aac', '-b:a', '128k'       ])
